# Hg update -C mercurial command equivalent in git

Tags: git, mercurial

Suppose I have made changes to several files in a git repository that was for exploratory purposes and now I want to undo all of my changes back to the original state.

If this was mercurial I would simply do

```
hg up -C
```

What is the proper way to acheive this in git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just wish to discard changes for just one file you can type:

```
git checkout -- <file>
```

(actually "git status" is giving you this hint).

If you want to throw away all local changes:

```
git checkout -f
```

Comment: -f seems to be exactly what i was looking for. I find it strange that none of the git<>hg comparison pages on the internet seemed to mention this.

Comment: I eventaully found out what the problem was, the git hg rosetta stone has had years of changes that have never been published. I forked the rosetta stone to allow those changes to actually be visible https://github.com/dotnetchris/Git-Hg-Rosetta-Stone/wiki

Comment: @ChrisMarisic actually I made my own little git/hg dictionary list in: http://cmuller.github.io/#using-git Instead of an exhaustive list, I focused on commands I use every day and.. `hg update -C` was in it.. ;-) Hope it'll help also. Forks and corrections are welcome.